# Image doesn't show HTML

Tags: html

I am completely new to coding and I am doing the responsive web design course on free code camp. I am trying to make a french bakery website to learn web development, but when I put an image, it doesn't appear. I tried to use an URL instead but it didn't work. So I tried the solutions that I saw on this website and others but none of the solutions worked. Thank for your help.

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOv9a.png)

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbWVz.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't really help you.  You haven't provided enough information.  Use your browser's developer tools to see what the problem is.  It's very likely you have the wrong URL for your image.  It's also possible you have invalid HTML.  But, you didn't show us any of that so it's hard to say...

Comment: you have to share your code

Comment: What's the image you are trying to add ? Do you have a link to the image ?

Comment: Why are you using "image\Baguettes.jpg" as a link ? There is no image folder.

Comment: Please do a good amount of search before asking such questions and learn how to display images in HTML.

Comment: Please post your code as a text instead of using images, [why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `images/Baguettes.jpg` by `Baguettes.jpg` because you don't have a folder named `ìmages`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any images folder

Do this:

```
<img src ="Baguettes.jpg">
```

Instead of:

```
<img src ="images\Baguettes.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have define wrong image path because your image is not in image folder so please replace the following

```
<img src ="images\Baguettes.jpg">

with 

<img src ="Baguettes.jpg">
```

or if you want the same path

```
<img src ="images\Baguettes.jpg">
```

then please add your image in "images" folder